# How to write a test case for useEffect and SetTimeout UseState in Jest React Native?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am facing issue with covering test for below mentioned code. Any one help me on this?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setOverlayState(isShowResult);
  if (isShowResult) {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setToggleState(false);
      setOverlayState(false);
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }, 3000);
  }
}, [isBundleAdded, isShowResult]);
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also `clearTimeout(timer)` inside of timeout does not make any sense. Probably it should be `return () => clearTimeout(timer);` right next to `setTimeout(....)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I covered all the scenario.. I did not write anything for setState scenario.